# CSS: Watermark over text but link clickable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text (DIV#my_text) with some `<A>` links and I want to place a watermark (DIV#watermark fixed, z-index: 5, background-image and opacity: .5) **over** this text but I want clickable links.

Actually I have a solution: duplicate #my_text with z-index: 10 and opacity: 0 but I don't like it for many reasons (like :hover problems).

Suggestions?

Comment: If watermark would be child of clickable element, then there would be no problem...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `pointer-events: none;` to the watermark DIV. This will allow you to click through it to the underlying elements.

```css
#watermark {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a id="text" href="http://stackoverflow.com">This link is clickable</a>
<div id="watermark">

</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9a1n5o5a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointer-events: none` to be able to click "through" the above element:

```css
div, a {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  width: 3em;
}

#under {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}

#above {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a id="under" href="http://google.fr"></a>
<div id="above"></div>
```